# Gunzip inside awk script

Tags: text-processing, awk

I am creating an output file inside an `awk` script which I want to compress then.

Input file - Marks.txt

```
Student1:AP:Maths:30:Science:43
Student2:AP:Maths:23:Science:35
Student3:Non_AP:Maths:17:Science:33
```

My code looks as below

```
BEGIN{
   FS = ":"
}

$2 == "AP"{
 print $3, $4 > "maths_AP.txt"
}

$2 == "Non_AP"{
 print $3, $4 > "maths_non_AP.txt"
}

{...} #some other processing not relevant to question
```

I want to create both `maths_AP.txt` and `maths_non_AP.txt` as zipped files. Some forums suggest using `gunzip` function but I can't understand how to place it in the script.

Comment: Why not compress the files after they've already been created, outside of the `awk` command?

Answer (score 8):

Awk is a tool for manipulating text. A shell is a tool for manipulating (creating/destroying) files and processes and sequencing calls to other tools. Therefore you shouldn't in general sequence calls to other tools from inside awk as that's the job of a shell, instead manipulate text with awk and then let the shell call any other tools, e.g. untested:

```
mkdir out &&
sort -t':' -k3,3 -k2,2 Marks.txt |
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS=":" }
    { key = "out/" $3 "_" $2 ".txt" }
    key != out {
        close(out)
        out = key
    }
    { print > out }
' &&
for file in out/*.txt; do
    zip "$file" &&
    rm -f "$file"         # assuming you want to discard the .txt file
done
```

The above will work using any versions of the tools. Any awk solution that doesn't call `close()` will fail in most awk versions once you get past some threshold of max number of simultaneously open files which I've seen be less than 20.

Answer (score 2):

compress can be done after, or during awk's run.

Try

```
$2 == "AP"{
 print $3, $4 > "maths_AP.txt" ;
 print $3, $4 | "gzip > maths_AP.gz" ;
}

$2 == "Non_AP"{
 print $3, $4 > "maths_non_AP.txt" ;
 print $3, $4 | "gzip > maths_non_AP.gz" ;
}
```

- you may run out of file descriptor if there is too many files to write.
- I ended awk's statement by `;` for ages before noticing it was optionnal.